# EF Code-First migrations ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Id failed because one or more objects access this column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having trouble updating the database, when I apply the migration I'm getting this error:

```
The object 'PK_dbo.CostCenter' is dependent on column 'Id'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN Id failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

I just tried to add a virtual property (CostCenter) to this table to be able to get that data

```
[Table("Department")]
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Cost> Costs_Department { get; set; }
    public virtual CostCenter CostCenter { get; set; }
}
```

This is the CostCenter table

```
[Table("CostCenter")]
public class CostCenter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

And another table related to Department

```
[Table("Cost")]
public class Cost
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Department Departament { get; set; }
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
}
```

The only change I added was the CostCenter property on the Department table, this is what VS created on the migrations file

```
public partial class CC : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CostCenter", "Department_CostCenter_Id", "dbo.Department");
        DropIndex("dbo.CostCenter", new[] { "Department_CostCenter_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.CostCenter", "Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.CostCenter", name: "Department_CostCenter_Id", newName: "Id");
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.CostCenter");
        AlterColumn("dbo.CostCenter", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.CostCenter", "Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.CostCenter", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.CostCenter", "Id", "dbo.Department", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.CostCenter", "Id", "dbo.Department");
        DropIndex("dbo.CostCenter", new[] { "Id" });
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.CostCenter");
        AlterColumn("dbo.CostCenter", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.CostCenter", "Id");
        RenameColumn(table: "dbo.CostCenter", name: "Id", newName: "Department_CostCenter_Id");
        AddColumn("dbo.CostCenter", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        CreateIndex("dbo.CostCenter", "Department_CostCenter_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.CostCenter", "Department_CostCenter_Id", "dbo.Department", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
}
```

I already have a relationship similar to this on other tables, so I don't know what's causing the problem this time

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and just remove all the previous migration files, create a new one and executed update-database command. If you can, also delete the database, Before it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you elaborate on this a little bit please? Maybe write out the commands needed to achieve this. I think that would make your answer easier to reproduce by other users. Cheers :)

Comment: I forgot about this question, If I remember correctly that's what I ended doing, I had to remove some previous migrations and recreate the database. Thanks!

Comment: That won't really be an option for systems already in production.

Answer (score 2):

Per suggested solution above, once you are in the production, dropping db won't be the case.

In my case,

- first I dropped the relation between two tables by editing my
  entities
- Then create a migration script which will have these changes
  (dropping relation changes)
- run update-database command.
- Then edit your entity to drop the column.
- Then create a migration script which will have most recent changes
  (dropping column)
- After that, edit your entities to have the relation again
- Then you can add another migration which will have the changes to
  re-create the relation between tables.
- As final step, run update-database command to publish changes.

Is this the best solution?

- I doubt about it.

Was it fixed the issue?

- Yes.

Comment: Sorry, edit the entity to drop the ID column? `The object 'PK_dbo.CostCenter' is dependent on column 'Id'.` What do you suggest should be the primary key, in this solution?